# Oracle SQL Query Returns Different Results via OLEDB Provider as Opposed to ODBC 10/11g Driver

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oledb

I have written a small application in the AutoIT scripting language which uses ADO to connect to both Oracle and MSSQL databases and run queries, alerting on their results.

Most of the time I can connect to an Oracle DB using ODBC and the standard 10/11g driver however on one of my client's servers this can't be done so I'm using the OLEDB provider as the connection method.

The query I'm using seems to return no results via OLEDB however via ODBC it works absolutely fine.

```
Select Submission_Session_ID,Acquirer_ID,TO_CHAR(Submission_Date,'DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI'),Total_Records,Status,round(Total_Net_Debit-Total_Net_Credit/100.0,2) FROM customer.SubmissionHistory WHERE Submission_Date >= (sysdate-1/24)
```

Does anyone have an understanding of why this could be the case?  At the very most I seem to be able to return one row from this query.

Comment: There appear to be a couple of backticks - \` - in your query - are they part of the query you are trying to run, or are they typos?

Comment: Apologies, this is my first post on here, I believe those ' were input when i tried to insert my query.  I've edited the post now.  THank you!

Comment: Please show your code.  If you try, "select 1 from dual" with OLEDB, does it return anything?

Comment: Ae you sure you actually have matching data on that particular server? Can you query without the filter to check what submission dates you have - at least check the latest date and see if that is in the last hour? Or with a different client - direct in SQL Plus maybe? I'd hazard a *very* wild guess that data is created based on `current_date` and that's a hour different from `sysdate`, so you might occasionally get a hit... or something in that area anyway.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `WHERE` clause (or use something other than a `DATE` column)? Do you get similar results then?

Comment: I've added some of my code hoping it helps clarify my connection but it might confuse a bit.  I've basically got a few includes where i keep connection routines and variables within different includes to make it easy to use throughout the whole application.

With regards to select 1 from dual, it returns the number 1 in row 1 - nothing else.

I've got 3 lots of data on my test kit that are all within the last 24 hours, normally as you can see from my code i put the hours to search as a variable so i can look back over the last x number of hours.

With no where clause I am still returning 1 row